# Duplication of entry when sharing content

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

When I click on share on a users link..It shares that post fine, yet it posts it twice. I've checked firebug and when clicked (Once) it shows up two POST requests, inserts two posts to the database and then shows them in the users feed. 
I really don't understand where I'm going wrong.

SHARE LINK

```
echo'<a class="sharelink" title="Share '.$poster_name['fullusersname'].'s status" href="#"
 data-streamitem_creator='.$streamitem_data['streamitem_creator'].'
 data-streamitem_target='.$_SESSION['id'].'
 data-streamitem_content='.$streamitem_data['streamitem_content'].'
 data-streamitem_type_id=4>Share</a>';
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.sharelink').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var streamitem_creator = $(this).data('streamitem_creator');
        var streamitem_target = $(this).data('streamitem_target');
        var streamitem_content = $(this).data('streamitem_content');
        var streamitem_type_id = $(this).data('streamitem_type_id');

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../include/share.php",
            data: {
                streamitem_creator: streamitem_creator,
                streamitem_target: streamitem_target,
                streamitem_content: streamitem_content,
                streamitem_type_id: streamitem_type_id
            },
            success: function(data) {
                $(".usermsg").html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

SHARE.php

```
<? 
session_start();
require"load.php";

if(isset($_POST['streamitem_type_id'])&isset($_POST['streamitem_creator'])&isset($_POST['streamitem_content'])&isset($_POST['streamitem_target'])){

user_core::create_streamitem(4,$_SESSION['id'],$_POST['streamitem_content'],1,$_POST['streamitem_creator']);

}
?>
```

LOAD.PHP

```
public function create_streamitem($typeid,$creatorid,$content,$ispublic,$targetuser){
    global $mysqli;
            $content = $content;
//          $content =  strip_tags($content);

            if(strlen($content)>0){

    $insert = "INSERT INTO streamdata(streamitem_type_id,streamitem_creator,streamitem_target,streamitem_timestamp,streamitem_content,streamitem_public) VALUES ($typeid,$creatorid,$targetuser,UTC_TIMESTAMP(),'$content',$ispublic)";
            $add_post = mysqli_query($mysqli,$insert) or die(mysqli_error($mysqli));
            $last_id  = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli); 
                if(!($creatorid==$targetuser)){
                    $fromuser= rawfeeds_user_core::getuser($creatorid);
                    $_SESSION['id']==$content;
            }       
            return;
            }else{
            return false;
            }
```

Comment: good ol' `global $database`...

Comment: see nothing that could produce two requests. What if you debug your click handler? Is it called twice? I bet it is. Possibly `$('.sharelink').click(function(e) {` is called twice. Have you checked this? Also - what if your mouse produce two clicks :)?

Comment: Besides, what is in `data` which is returned after request?

Comment: Nothing at the moment. Its going to hold Modal box with a success when I've sorted out this. But it does the same with or without the success (data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see any problem.. By any chance, don't you have that `$('.sharelink').click` handler registered twice within your page?

Comment: No. All my requests are in one file, so I'd know if that were the case. I did use FIND in dreamweaver for any duplicate classes and such too. Trying your Return false. But hasn't made a different.

Comment: Here is a workaround suggestion http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-prevent-ajax-request-firing-twice/

Comment: I look into it and see what I can do. Thanks so much.

Comment: I  may try the Ajax with a button. Seems to be the Ajax that is the problem, a normal link straight the the share.php page only inserts a single entry.